# math.stackexchange.com is frozen in Chrome.

Tags: support, mathjax, google-chrome

For some reason http://math.stackexchange.com is being frozen in Chrome.

I can use all stackexchange websites in chrome except mathematics - the page just freezes and no actions or clicks are being recognized by the page.

Comment: What about physics and MathOverflow, and other sites which have MathJax enabled?

Comment: Yes, these two are also frozen for me in Chrome.

Comment: Then it's probably due to MathJax clashing with something in your computer.

Comment: Thank you, I've installed MathJax plugin from Chrome Webstore and now everything is fine.

Comment: MathJax is known to be very unstable un Chrome, with frequent AW Snap crashes etc that can cause loss of work. There are many prior reports here of such. It doesn't appear that it will ever be fixed since the MathJax developers claim it is a bug in Chrome. I gave up using MSE in Chrome after losing more work combined than in my entire online life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing [MathJax plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathjax-for-chrome/elbbpgnifnallkilnkofjcgjeallfcfa?hl=en-GB) for chrome helped me.

Comment: Which one exactly? Your link has gone dead by now